# MySQL alias fails in ELSE part of CASE statement (Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'xxx' in 'field list')

Tags: mysql, alias

I have been searching online all day and can't find an answer to this problem.

MySQL Statement as follows:

```
SELECT h.idhighsite AS idhighsite, h.number AS number, h.name AS name, i.ip AS mainbridge, b.branch AS branch, d.district AS district, a.area AS area, h.repeaterheight AS height,
       h.contract AS contract, h.eiastatus AS eia, COUNT(c.idhscontact) AS contactcount, 
       
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.contact) AS contacts,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.isexisting) AS isexisting,
       GROUP_CONCAT(c.cellid) AS cellid,
       
       CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(isexisting,',',1) = 1 THEN 
           CASE 
               WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',1) = 1 THEN cu.name1
               WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',1) = 2 THEN cu.name2
               WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',1) = 3 THEN cu.name3
           END 
       ELSE 
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(contacts,',',1) /* <--- This Fails*/
       END AS name1
       
FROM wmdevl.highsite h 

LEFT JOIN wmdevl.hsitem i ON (i.idhighsite = h.idhighsite AND i.mainbridge = True)
LEFT JOIN wmdevl.branch b ON (b.idbranch = h.idbranch)
LEFT JOIN wmdevl.district d ON (d.iddistrict = h.iddistrict)
LEFT JOIN wmdevl.area a ON (a.idarea = h.idarea)
LEFT JOIN wmdevl.hscontact c ON (c.idhighsite = h.idhighsite) 
LEFT JOIN wmdevl.customer cu ON (cu.idcustomer = c.idcustomer)

GROUP BY h.idhighsite;
```

When I comment out the problematic "SUBSTRING_INDEX(contacts,',',1)" then it works and it does show the column in the output.

Comment: Output column alias cannot be reused in another output column expression. Either use source column expression (`GROUP_CONCAT(c.cellid)`) instead of alias or convert the query to subquery/cte and reuse in outer query.

Comment: @Akina Thanks.
It is a many to many relation, and I have a flag "isexisting" that relates to customer table.
If "isexisitng" is false, I must use the contact in the hscontact table and not the relating customer.

Is there a way I can set a variable to "SUBSTRING_INDEX(contacts,',',1)" and use it as alias "name1"?

Comment: Can you try changing `SUBSTRING_INDEX(contacts,',',1)` to `IFNULL(contacts, "", SUBSTRING_INDEX(contacts,',',1));`?  My only suspicion I can think of is that you're not finding any hscontact records.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger Thanks. But I get exactly the same error. I believe Akina is correct about trying to use an alias in another output column expression. I am going to try subquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Akina putting me in the right direction a subquery is what worked:

```
SELECT *,

   CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(isexisting,',',1) = 1 THEN 
       CASE 
           WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',1) = 1 THEN cuname1
           WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',1) = 2 THEN cuname2
           WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',1) = 3 THEN cuname3
       END 
   ELSE 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(contacts,',',1) 
   END AS name1,
   
   CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(isexisting,',',1) = 1 THEN 
       CASE 
           WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',1) = 1 THEN cucell1
           WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',1) = 2 THEN cucell2
           WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',1) = 3 THEN cucell3
       END 
   ELSE 
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(numbers,',',1) 
   END AS number1,
   
   CASE WHEN contactcount >= 2 THEN
       CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(isexisting,',',2), ',', -1) = 1 THEN 
           CASE 
               WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',2), ',', -1) = 1 THEN cuname1
               WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',2), ',', -1) = 2 THEN cuname2
               WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',2), ',', -1) = 3 THEN cuname3
           END 
       ELSE 
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(contacts,',',2), ',', -1)
       END 
   END AS name2,

   CASE WHEN contactcount >= 2 THEN
       CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(isexisting,',',2), ',', -1) = 1 THEN 
           CASE 
               WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',2), ',', -1) = 1 THEN cucell1
               WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',2), ',', -1) = 2 THEN cucell2
               WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',2), ',', -1) = 3 THEN cucell3
           END 
       ELSE 
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(numbers,',',2), ',', -1) 
       END 
   END AS number2,
   
   CASE WHEN contactcount >= 3 THEN
       CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(isexisting,',',3), ',', -1) = 1 THEN 
           CASE 
               WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',3), ',', -1) = 1 THEN cuname1
               WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',3), ',', -1) = 2 THEN cuname2
               WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',3), ',', -1) = 3 THEN cuname3
           END 
       ELSE 
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(contacts,',',3), ',', -1)
       END 
   END AS name3,

   CASE WHEN contactcount >= 3 THEN
       CASE WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(isexisting,',',3), ',', -1) = 1 THEN 
           CASE 
               WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',3), ',', -1) = 1 THEN cucell1
               WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',3), ',', -1) = 2 THEN cucell2
               WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(cellid,',',3), ',', -1) = 3 THEN cucell3
           END 
       ELSE 
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(numbers,',',3), ',', -1) 
       END 
   END AS number3
       
FROM (SELECT h.idhighsite AS idhighsite, h.number AS number, h.name AS name, i.ip AS mainbridge, b.branch AS branch, d.district AS district, a.area AS area, h.repeaterheight AS height,
    h.contract AS contract, h.eiastatus AS eia, cu.name1 AS cuname1, cu.name2 AS cuname2, cu.name3 AS cuname3, cu.cell1 AS cucell1, cu.cell2 AS cucell2, cu.cell3 AS cucell3,
    h.notes AS notes, h.caastatus AS caastatus, h.anticollight AS anticollight, h.contractdate AS contractdate, h.evergreen AS evergreen, h.rentescallation AS escallationdate, h.rentamount AS rent,

    COUNT(c.idhscontact) AS contactcount, 

    GROUP_CONCAT(c.contact) AS contacts,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.number) AS numbers,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.isexisting) AS isexisting,
    GROUP_CONCAT(c.cellid) AS cellid

    FROM highsite h 

    LEFT JOIN hsitem i ON (i.idhighsite = h.idhighsite AND i.mainbridge = True)
    LEFT JOIN branch b ON (b.idbranch = h.idbranch)
    LEFT JOIN district d ON (d.iddistrict = h.iddistrict)
    LEFT JOIN area a ON (a.idarea = h.idarea)
    LEFT JOIN hscontact c ON (c.idhighsite = h.idhighsite) 
    LEFT JOIN customer cu ON (cu.idcustomer = c.idcustomer)

    GROUP BY h.idhighsite) 
AS x;
```